How can I safely remove duplicates from Photo?
When I have looked how to delete duplicates from my Photo library Apple says use the 'duplicates' option on the photo menu.  Except my version of Photo doesn't have this button (Version 7.0 (460.0.120)).
My photo library is on iCloud and also backed up on a removable drive.
What can I do please?


Except my version of Photo doesn't have this button (Version 7.0 (460.0.120))

Apple didn’t implement Remove Duplicates until Ventura. From this Mac Keeper article:

since macOS Ventura, the Mac Photos app will automatically detect duplicates as you import them.

This is (sort of) confirmed by the Photos User Guide that only shows these advanced features for Ventura and Sonoma.
The only thing you can do to get this feature is upgrade your OS to Ventura or newer.
